# Vector/ArrayList of Objects to JList? - Java

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I've run into a problem with my code that I haven't encountered before and can't seem to fix. Basically, I am trying to create a GUI application that will allow the user to search for a name ("Ryan" for example) and will search a CSV file, displaying results to a JScrollPane(JList). Below is the code I have so far, which as shown populates the list by repeating the last element of the Vector n number of times (which is wrong, each element in the Vector should print once)...

Main code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SeatingChart extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

static JLabel search = new JLabel("Search for: ");
static JTextField se = new JTextField("Cap 1st Letter Of Name", 15);
static JButton submit = new JButton("submit");

Vector<Employee> employees = new Vector<Employee>(5, 1); //Works fine with Vector< String >
JList results = new JList(employees); 
JScrollPane display = new JScrollPane(results);

public SeatingChart()
{
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    //Add things to Panels
    JPanel north = new JPanel();
    north.add(search);
    north.add(se);
    north.add(submit);

    JPanel west = new JPanel();
    west.add(display);

    //Add panels to Frame
    panel.add(north, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panel.add(west, BorderLayout.WEST);

    add(panel);

    // Register listeners
    submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        search(se.getText()); //call search and sort method
        results.setListData(employees);
      }});
    results.addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseListener(this);

} //end constructor

public void search(String s)
{
    try{
        BufferedReader CSVFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("ADexport.csv"));
        String dataRow = CSVFile.readLine(); // Read first line.  

        // The while checks to see if the file is empty 
        while (dataRow != null) 
        {
            if(dataRow.contains(s)) { //Line by line
                String[] dataArray = dataRow.split(",");
                employees.addElement(new Employee(dataArray[0], dataArray[1], dataArray[2], dataArray[3])); //Add .toString() if Vector< String >
            } //end if
            dataRow = CSVFile.readLine(); /*Read next line*/
        }

        CSVFile.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Unexpected error.");
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
    }
} //end search method

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    int index = results.getSelectedIndex();
    Employee selected = (Employee) results.getSelectedValue();

    System.out.println("Clicked! " + index);
}
```

Employee class:

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class Employee {
public static String name;
public static String type;
public static String pos;
public static String ex;

public Employee(String n, String t, String p, String e)
{
    name = n;
    type = t;
    pos = p;
    ex = e;
}

public String toString()
{
    return this.name + " " + this.ex;
}

public String getName()
{
    return this.name;
}

public String getex()
{
    return this.ex;
}
}
```

And here is the information from the CSV file I have been using:

```
Name    Type    Description Office
Ryan Cole   User    Manager Ext. 115
Ryan Ketricks   User    Staff   Ext. 116
Ryan James  User    Senior  Ext. 117
Luke Alexander  User    Staff   Ext. 118
Michael Kale    User    Senior  Ext. 119
Alyssa Win  User    Staff   Ext. 120
Kayla Bofort    User    Partner Ext. 121
```

The thing is, when I use Vector < String > everything works fine, but I can't cast from String to Employee. I would like to retain the Employee type anyway since I want to use that information again when the MouseEvent is triggered. Essentially, I would like to know why it works with String but not Employee, and how to fix.

Comment: Why are all your Employee fields `static`?

Comment: @AliceRenee you can find the answer in the comment by @searlea. I don't have enough reputation to add a comment, so I just want to add: add commas in your CSV file between the fields, otherwise you will get an index-out-bounds exception after doing the `split()`.

Comment: @searlea I don't know... I removed it and it solved my problem. Thanks, I can't believe I missed that!